# Solr field collapsing

Tags: solr, fieldcollapsing

I read
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

and I tried the query
http://192.168.0.1:8080/solr/append/select?q=mobile&group=true&group.field=brand

and I don't see the field collapsing. I mean I see the results, but not the grouping. My understanding is it should work, nothing to change in the solrconfig.xml ? In my schema, all my field are stored/index. My index is Lucene 2.9 and my Solr is 1.4.1. I don't see what I doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field collapsing is not available in Solr 1.4.1. You need Solr 3.3 or 4.0 (currently unreleased).

The wiki page about field collapsing also explains "If you haven't already, get a recent nightly build of Solr4.0 or Solr3.3..."

Look for "warning tags" in the Solr wiki that show when a particular feature is available only since a particular version of Solr:

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you, I got a little bit mixed up with the Solr versions. So now, it is not clear to me what is the difference between 4.0 and 3.3. Which one should I use ? They are mentionning on the wiki a future 1.4.2 also ?

Comment: @Bob: 1.4.2 will probably never be released. 3.3 is probably going to be released next. 4.0 has many new features, but may be more unstable than 3.x. Unless you need a 4.x feature, I'd stick with 3.x